# Existence of Best approximation in infinite dimensional inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, approximation

I know that for a finite dimensional inner product space,the best approximation of a vector exists in a given subspace not containing the vector.But is it true for infinite dimensional inner product space.In general,I have shown that it is not true for normed spaces because we can take the sup norm $||.||$ on $C[0,1]$ and we can take the function $f(x)=e^x$ and approximate it by a sequence of polynomials,but $e^x$ is not in the subspace spanned by those polynomials. 
But I could not find an easy example for infinite dimensional inner product space,can someone give an example of an infinite dimensional inner product space,where best approximation does not exist?

Does the following example work $V$ be the vector space of all eventually zero sequences in $\mathbb R$ and define the inner product $<\sigma,\mu>=\sum \sigma(n)\mu(n)$ and take the subspace $W={\sigma_n(k):n>1}$ where $\sigma_n=e_1+e_n$ where $e_n(k)=\delta_{n,k}$,consider $e_1$,does it have a best approximation in $W$?

Comment: In any infinite-dimensional Banach space there exists a basic sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ by a theorem of Mazur.  Take any $x$ in the closed span of $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ but not in its span.  This includes Hilbert spaces, which are special kinds of Banach spaces with a norm induced by an inner product.

Comment: @Ben I don't know Banach space,please give me an explicit example.

Comment: You should look it up, because Banach spaces are awesome : )  In the mean time, here's an explicit example:  Consider the space (called $\ell_2$) of scalar sequences $(a_n)$ satisfying $\sum|a_n|^2<\infty$, endowed with the norm $\|(a_n)\|=\sqrt{\sum|a_n|^2}$.  Let $Y$ be the subspace of eventually-zero sequences.  Then $(1/n)_{n=1}^\infty$ belongs to $\ell_2$, but has no best approximation in $Y$.  Note that $\ell_2$ is an inner product space (in fact, a Hilbert space).